# Console.ReadKey Unexpected Behavior with Pasted Text - Multi-Keys Entered at Once

Tags: c#, .net, console

Call `Console.ReadKey()` and at the prompt do a PASTE (Edit->Paste) of any clipboard text where Length > 1 (let's say 'Hello World!').

I just discovered that unexpectedly, on subsequent calls to Console.ReadKey(), instead presenting a prompt to the user, no prompt is given! Instead, subsequent characters from the pasted text are read ... with NO prompt!

**BOTTOM LINE: To use ReadKey, I need to make sure (darn well sure) when I call ReadKey the next time, that it actually gives the user a prompt. Currently, this makes ReadKey unusable for critical scenarios like this.**

It does not look like there is any way to disable this, or to simply clear the inputted but not yet read out values.

In my case, this presented critical errors into the simple console app, where I was looping looking for either the words 'R' for 'RUN', or any 'E' to 'END'. Since near to this time I prompt for a file path, it was fairly easy at this point for the user who has already used it to paste the file path at this point on a accident. Problem is (!!!), if that file path contained an 'r', it immediately Runs.

```
using System;

namespace Practise1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            RunDialogue2();
        }

        public static void RunDialogue()
        {
            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine("Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END");
                ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

                switch (key) {
                    case ConsoleKey.R:
                        Console.WriteLine("RUN! ENGINES BLAST OFF!");
                        BlastOff();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.E:
                        Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
                        return;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("INVALID ENTRY, TRY AGAIN");
                        // we *thought* this would pick up bad input, but not pasted text!
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        public static void RunDialogue2()
        {
            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine("Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END");
                ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

                switch (key) {
                    case ConsoleKey.R:
                        Console.WriteLine("RUN! ENGINES BLAST OFF!");
                        Console.WriteLine("We blasted off at: " + DateTime.UtcNow);
                        //BlastOff();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.E:
                        Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
                        return;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("INVALID ENTRY, TRY AGAIN");
                        // we *thought* this would pick up bad input, but not pasted text!
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you had 'Charley's!' in your clipboard and pasted it, here is the output. Notice how you can get multiple RUNs! All unintended. Quite scary how bad this is, it would mean to me we can NEVER depend on ReadKey as a realiable input method, particularly when we thought we were validating the input:

```
Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END
C

INVALID ENTRY, TRY AGAIN
Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END
h

INVALID ENTRY, TRY AGAIN
Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END
a

INVALID ENTRY, TRY AGAIN
Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END
r

RUN! ENGINES BLAST OFF!
We blasted off at: 7/21/2013 11:24:36 PM
Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END
l

INVALID ENTRY, TRY AGAIN
Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END
e

FINISHED
```

I know a solution would be to use Console.ReadLine instead, but the ability to interact immediately with a single key press was much happier. Is there any way around this odd behavior?

Comment: I wouldn't say that the user isn't getting a prompt.  The prompt is printed, and then the read is fulfilled from the input buffer.  Usually that's desired behavior for console applications (it lets you paste responses to multiple questions at a time), but in your case flush the buffer as tinstaafl showed.  Although I would flush the buffer right before printing the prompt.

Comment: So who voted down my question? Absolutely despicable.

Comment: ben is right,because like i said in comment in my answer i tested and all was correct

Comment: @BenVoigt 'I wouldn't say that the user isn't getting a prompt.' - Personally, I would much prefer that ReadKey only accept one key from the input, and discard the rest.  But hey, I wouldn't vote people down for such differences of opinion. I don't care how it is worded, so long as you weren't voting down this question for a minor wording semantics issue.

Comment: i didnt downvoted also.

Comment: Okay, thank you Ben and terrybozzio. Can anyone equal things out then and at least get it back to 0? That's what I hate about some people's conduct here, I worked hard to give a cogent full code example, and I still get my butt kicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will get rid of constant reads by readkey:

```
    public static void RunDialogue()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END");
            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
            switch (key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.R:
                    Console.WriteLine("RUN! ENGINES BLAST OFF!");
                    BlastOff();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.E:
                    Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
                    return;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("INVALID ENTRY, TRY AGAIN");
                    // we *thought* this would pick up bad input, but not pasted text!
                    break;
            }
            Console.In.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
```

While that will get rid of the immediate problem in the original post, a more complete solution would be to read and ignore the rest of the input stream without echoing it to the screen, something like this will work:

```
    public static void RunDialogue()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END");
            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
            switch (key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.R:
                    Console.WriteLine("RUN! ENGINES BLAST OFF!");
                    BlastOff();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.E:
                    Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
                    return;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("INVALID ENTRY, TRY AGAIN");
                    // we *thought* this would pick up bad input, but not pasted text!
                    break;
            }
            while (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Actually the op said he doesn't want readkey reading the rest of the input buffer and assigning it to `key`, which you seemed to have missed in your answer.  Both my solutions in this answer address that but like I said the second one is a more complete solution.

Comment: Dude, rock on. I thought I tried everything, but I missed 'Console.KeyAvailable'. Way groovy. Now I still am disappointed by the fact the Console.ReadKey allows more than one key entered, because it still means (in my example) if it started with an 'R' or 'E', that those are treated as the actual command, whereas multiple chars should just be rejected. Actually that gives me an idea of who to solve this, see following.

Comment: The behavior you've seen is actually the default behavior of the Console, and works for a great many applications just the way it is.  As you've seen though, there are usually simple ways to modify this behavior.

Comment: through this experience I have indeed learned that this is the (unexpected!) behavior, unexpected at least for me, though I think many others would not have known this. But isn't this the very point of StackOverflow? I.e. if you voted down my question for this, what's the point of SO if you can't ask questions?

Comment: I didn't down vote your question or have any idea who did.  One thing to consider is there might be an obscure violation of what is expected when asking questions, which of course are always open to personal interpretation.  That's one of the drawbacks of sites like this.  down votes can happen for any number of reasons even personal pique.  Personally unless the person is adult and professional enough  to point out why there was a down vote, they're not worth considering or even thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the answer by @tinstaafl, which revealed the key solution by checking on `Console.KeyAvailable`. While I am definitely and in all fairness leaving that answer as the solution, the following is the final solution that covers scenarios in which you must completely verify the input is truly only a single char.

```
        public static ConsoleKey ReadKeySingle(bool intercept = false, ConsoleKey errorKey = ConsoleKey.Clear)
        {
            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(intercept).Key;
            while (Console.KeyAvailable) {
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                key = errorKey;
            }
            return key;
        }
```

Then use it like this (single line change):

```
        public static void RunDialogue()
        {
            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine("Type 'R' to RUN, 'E' to END");

                // KEY! Call ReadKeySingle instead
                ConsoleKey key = ReadKeySingle(); // Console.ReadKey().Key; //!!!

                Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

                switch (key) {
                    case ConsoleKey.R:
                        Console.WriteLine("RUN! ENGINES BLAST OFF!");
                        Console.WriteLine("We blasted off at: " + DateTime.UtcNow);

                        // BlastOff();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.E:
                        Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
                        return;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("INVALID ENTRY, TRY AGAIN");
                        // we *thought* this would pick up bad input, but not pasted text!
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```